# Query within a foreach within a query (queryception)

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, wp-query, users

I'm achieving [this list](https://i.gyazo.com/4a78da9e378922e3640fd1cb3e142e49.png) in a really roundabout way at the moment and I feel like I should be able to do it with a foreach instead of separate queries for each "House" (House is a CPT and is assigned as usermeta too), but I can't get it to work.

Currently doing it with these queries for EACH House (manually writing in the ID of the 'House' post for each new query):

```
$houseid = '8490'; //Manually changing this id each time, so I have the code below repeated a bunch...
 $connectors = get_users( array( 
  'fields' => 'ID',
  'meta_query' => array(
   'relation' => 'OR',
   'house' => array(
    'key' => 'house',
    'value' => $houseid,
   ),
   'leader_of_house' => array(
    'key' => 'leader_of_house',
    'value' => $houseid,
   ),
  )
 ) );
$connections = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'connection', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'author__in' => $connectors ) );
$total = $connections->found_posts; if ( !empty ( $total ) ) { echo '<span class="connector"><p>' . get_the_title($houseid) . ' (' . $connections->found_posts . ' connections)</p></span>'; }
```

So I've started writing a foreach instead to loop through those House IDs I was manually writing in before, but it's not working (it's just showing one result, which is the title of page I'm writing this code on). Here's my current attempt:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'house', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );
$houses = $the_query->get_posts();
foreach( $posts as $post ) {
 $houseid = $post->ID;
 $connectors = get_users( array( 
  'fields' => 'ID',
  'meta_query' => array(
   'relation' => 'OR',
   'house' => array(
    'key' => 'house',
    'value' => $houseid,
   ),
   'leader_of_house' => array(
    'key' => 'leader_of_house',
    'value' => $houseid,
   ),
  ),
 ) );
 $connections = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'connection', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'author__in' => $connectors ) );
 $total = $connections->found_posts; if ( !empty ( $total ) ) { echo '<span class="connector"><p>' . get_the_title($houseid) . ' (' . $connections->found_posts . ' connections)</p></span>'; }
}
```

Can anyone tell me where I've gone wrong?

The goal is to list each "House" and then tally up the number of "Connections" (also a CPT) which the authors assigned to each House have created. Like a scoreboard. So House > Users with matching meta (House ID) > Connections created by those users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good for you that you've corrected the `$posts` that was undefined, but then:

1. There's no need to call `$the_query->get_posts()` because when `WP_Query` is instantiated with *a non-empty query*, e.g. `new WP_Query( 'post_type=house' )` (contains one query arg — `post_type`) as opposed to `new WP_Query()` (no query args specified), the [`get_posts()` method](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/get_posts/) in that class will automatically be called.
2. If you were trying to get the posts that were already fetched by the specific query, then `get_posts()` is not actually for that purpose. On the contrary, it will re-parse the query args, apply various filters, etc. and then re-query the database for the posts matching the query args. ( So basically, the same query is gonna be duplicated and it's not good.. )

   So how can you get that already fetched posts?

   Easy: Use the [`$posts` property](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#properties), i.e. `$the_query->posts` in your case.
3. Referring to your second query (`$connections`), if you just want to access the value of `$found_posts`, then you should just set the `posts_per_page` to `1` and not `-1`.

   ( As an aside, I've been hoping `WP_Query` would implement something like [`fields=count`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#return-fields-parameter) so that we could easily get the total number of found posts in the database.. )

Now as for this (from your comment): **how to sort the results by the number in `$total`**, rather than echoing in your `foreach`, you can store the totals (and post IDs) in an array and then sort and echo them afterwards.

Here's an example where I store them in an array named `$list` and used [`usort()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to sort them — by the `$total` value, *or* the house name (post title) if the total is equal:

```php
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'      => 'house',
    // Note: Instead of -1, you should use a high number like 99999..
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
) );

// each item is: array( <total connections>, <post ID>, <post title> )
$list = array();

foreach ( $the_query->posts as $post ) {
    $connectors = get_users( array(
        'fields'     => 'ID',
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key'   => 'house',
                'value' => $post->ID,
            ),
            array(
                'key'   => 'leader_of_house',
                'value' => $post->ID,
            ),
        ),
    ) );

    if ( empty( $connectors ) ) {
        continue;
    }

    $connections = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type'      => 'connection',
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'author__in'     => $connectors,
    ) );

    if ( $connections->found_posts ) {
        $list[] = array( $connections->found_posts, $post->ID, $post->post_title );
    }
}

// Sort by the total connections, or the post title instead if the total is equal.
usort( $list, function ( $a, $b ) {
    return $a[0] === $b[0] ? strcasecmp( $a[2], $b[2] ) : $b[0] > $a[0];
} );

if ( ! empty( $list ) ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ( $list as $item ) {
        list ( $total, $post_id ) = $item;

        echo '<li><span class="connector">' . esc_html( get_the_title( $post_id ) ) .
            " ($total connections)</span></li>";
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

And with that, the first three items in [this list](https://i.gyazo.com/4a78da9e378922e3640fd1cb3e142e49.png) would be displayed in the following order — the first two items have 4 connections, so they are instead sorted alphabetically in ascending order: (In MySQL, this is equivalent to `ORDER BY total DESC, LOWER( post_title ) ASC`)

```
Chapman, Robinson & Moore House (4 connections)
Databasix House (4 connections)
Aston & James House (2 connections)
```

So is that how you wanted the list be sorted? :)

Comment: Gosh, thank you so much. You didn't have to go to all that effort! It's perfect - Exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 0):

Ah I did it. I'd just cocked up the names of some identifiers in the example above. This works for anyone who may be interested:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'house', 'fields' => 'ID', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );
$posts = $the_query->get_posts();
foreach( $posts as $post ) {
 $connectors = get_users( array( 
  'fields' => 'ID',
  'meta_query' => array(
   'relation' => 'OR',
   'house' => array(
    'key' => 'house',
    'value' => $post->ID,
   ),
   'leader_of_house' => array(
    'key' => 'leader_of_house',
    'value' => $post->ID,
   ),
  ),
 ) );
$connections = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'connection', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'author__in' => $connectors ) );
$total = $connections->found_posts; if ( !empty ( $total ) ) { echo '<span class="connector"><p>' . get_the_title($post->ID) . ' (' . $total . ' connections)</p></span>'; }
}
```

Comment: If anyone has any idea how to sort the results by the number in $total I'd really appreciate the help.

Comment: Check my answer, but I used a `ul` instead of `p` to display the list.. let me know. :)